# jvectormap Show label and hand cursor on specific regions

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I have been trying to findout how to change the cursor to the hand for specific regions and show the label for only those regions.

I have this but am at a loss of how to do this. Can someone please help?

```
$(function(){
    var RColor = '#007cc4'
    var activeRegions = [
        "al", "an", "ey", "gh", "ic", "ke", "mu", "mz", "na", "ni", "za", "tz", "tu", "ug"
    ];
      $('#africa-map').vectorMap({
          map: 'africa',
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          zoomOnScroll: false,
          zoomButtons : false,
          regionStyle: {                  
              initial: {
                fill: '#b7bdc3',
                scaleColors: ['#b7bdc3', '#a2aaad'],
                "fill-opacity": 1,
                stroke: '#a2aaad',
                "stroke-width": 2,
                "stroke-opacity": 1
              },
              hover: {
                "fill-opacity": 0.8
              },
              selected: {
                fill: '#a2aaad'
              },
              selectedHover: {
                fill: '#a2aaad'
              }
            },
            series: {
                regions: [{values: {
                    "al" : RColor,
                    "an" : RColor,
                    "ey" : RColor,
                    "gh" : RColor,
                    "ic" : RColor,
                    "ke" : RColor,
                    "mu" : RColor,
                    "mz" : RColor,
                    "na" : RColor,
                    "ni" : RColor,
                    "za" : RColor,
                    "tz" : RColor,
                    "tu" : RColor,
                    "ug" : RColor
                    },
                    attribute: 'fill'
                    }]
                },               
              onRegionClick: function(event, code)
              {
                if (code == "al") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2918$'}
                if (code == "an") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2922$'}
                if (code == "ey") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2919$'}
                if (code == "gh") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2937$'}
                if (code == "ic") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2918$'}
                if (code == "ke") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2923$'}
                if (code == "mu") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2924$'}
                if (code == "mz") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2925$'}
                if (code == "na") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2926$'}
                if (code == "ni") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2927$'}
                if (code == "tz") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2929$'}
                if (code == "tu") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2930$'}
                if (code == "ug") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2931$'}
                if (code == "za") {window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2928$'}
              },
              onRegionOver: function(event, code)
              {                                         
                var mouseX;
                var mouseY;
                $('path.jvectormap-region.jvectormap-element').mousemove( function(e) {                    
                   var offset = $('#africa-map').offset();                     
                   mouseX = e.pageX- (offset.top)+20; 
                   mouseY = e.pageY- (offset.top)-25;
                   $(".region-info-box."+code).css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX});
                });  
                $(".region-info-box").hide();
                $(".region-info-box."+code).css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('fast');
              }
        });
    });
```

There is a `onRegionOver` but am at a loss to get it show the hand cursor and labels for only the regions listed above.

Here is a jsfiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/a9Xj6/2/ [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/a9Xj6/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you can make use of the `onRegionOver` event and also `onRegionLabelShow` for the label manipulation. Returning `false` in callback will stop the execution of the function, in this case we can stop execution of the label rendering when hovering a region.

To change the cursor to a `hand`, you can accomplish it using javascript.

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
```

Some sample code to help you further:

```
var regionResults = {
    "AL" : RColor,
    "AN" : RColor,
    "EY" : RColor,
    "GH" : RColor,
    "IC" : RColor,
    "KE" : RColor,
    "MU" : RColor,
    "MZ" : RColor,
    "NA" : RColor,
    "NI" : RColor,
    "ZA" : RColor,
    "TZ" : RColor,
    "TU" : RColor,
    "UG" : RColor
};

new jvm.WorldMap({
    // your map settings
    series: {
        regions: [{
            values: regionResults,
            attribute: 'fill'
        }]
    },
    onRegionOver: function(e, code) {
        if (regionResults.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
            // the hovered region is part of the regionResults, show hand cursor
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        }
    },
    onRegionOut: function(e, code) {
        // return to normal cursor
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    },
    onRegionLabelShow: function(e, label, code) {
        if (!regionResults.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
            // the hovered region is not part of the regionResults, don't show the label
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

**Update #1**

Here is the update of your code by integrating your 2 questions.

```
$(function() {
    var RColor = '#007cc4',
        activeRegions = {
            "AL" : RColor,
            "AN" : RColor,
            "EY" : RColor,
            "GH" : RColor,
            "IC" : RColor,
            "KE" : RColor,
            "MU" : RColor,
            "MZ" : RColor,
            "NA" : RColor,
            "NI" : RColor,
            "ZA" : RColor,
            "TZ" : RColor,
            "TU" : RColor,
            "UG" : RColor
        };

    $('#africa-map').vectorMap({
        map: 'africa',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        zoomOnScroll: false,
        zoomButtons: false,
        regionStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: '#b7bdc3',
                scaleColors: ['#b7bdc3', '#a2aaad'],
                "fill-opacity": 1,
                stroke: '#a2aaad',
                "stroke-width": 2,
                "stroke-opacity": 1
            },
            hover: {
                "fill-opacity": 0.8
            },
            selected: {
                fill: '#a2aaad'
            },
            selectedHover: {
                fill: '#a2aaad'
            }
        },
        series: {
            regions: [{
                values: activeRegions,
                attribute: 'fill'
            }]
        },
        onRegionClick: function(event, code)
        {
            code = code.toLowerCase();

            if (code == "al") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2918$';
            }
            if (code == "an") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2922$';
            }
            if (code == "ey") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2919$';
            }
            if (code == "gh") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2937$';
            }
            if (code == "ic") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2918$';
            }
            if (code == "ke") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2923$';
            }
            if (code == "mu") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2924$';
            }
            if (code == "mz") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2925$';
            }
            if (code == "na") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2926$';
            }
            if (code == "ni") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2927$';
            }
            if (code == "tz") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2929$';
            }
            if (code == "tu") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2930$';
            }
            if (code == "ug") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2931$';
            }
            if (code == "za") {
                window.location = '$AC:MENUURL:2928$';
            }
        },
        onRegionOver: function(event, code)
        {
            if (activeRegions.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
                // the hovered region is part of the regionResults, show hand cursor
                document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            }

            var mouseX;
            var mouseY;
            $('path.jvectormap-region.jvectormap-element').mousemove(function(e) {
                var offset = $('#africa-map').offset();
                mouseX = e.pageX - (offset.top) + 20;
                mouseY = e.pageY - (offset.top) - 25;
                $(".region-info-box." + code).css({'top': mouseY, 'left': mouseX});
            });
            $(".region-info-box").hide();
            $(".region-info-box." + code).css({'top': mouseY, 'left': mouseX}).fadeIn('fast');
        },
        onRegionOut: function(e, code) {
            // return to normal cursor
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        },
        onRegionLabelShow: function(e, label, code) {
            if (!activeRegions.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
                // the hovered region is not part of the regionResults, don't show the label
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the help! I edited my javascript since i am not quite sure how to implement your code with mine. I am using an africa map and noticed you have jvm.WorldMap. Does that matter?

Comment: You're welcome! No doesn't matter, normally should work with each type of map. I updated my answer with your code.

Comment: Wow this looks awesome and if it works i cant tell you how much i appreciate the help. Been looking everywhere for an answer.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle so you can see it working and how it does not show the hand or labels anymore. http://jsfiddle.net/a9Xj6/2/

Comment: You missed some code I've put in the answer. I've updated the fiddle and it is working now: http://jsfiddle.net/a9Xj6/3/

Comment: Can i ask you one more quick question? The div that shows on hover of a region is buggy in IE and does not line up correctly on various browsers. On some it is under the cursor and on other is it offset like it should be. Is there a better way to attach the div like i have it and make it offset when you hover over a region?

Comment: It seems because you are adding the `mousemove` event on each regionHover which causes multiple positioning code on the same element. It is best to unbind first to be sure that the `mousemove` callback is executed once. Also for the position calculation, it is better to use mouse position instead of an offset calculation based on parent element. I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a9Xj6/4/ :)

Comment: This looks great! One last issue is it seems to move the div farther away from the mouse when you view it on a wider screen and it puts over the region on smaller screens. It is not positioning it absolutely next to the mouse no matter the width or resolution. something it seems to do with the row div it is in and the width of 980. i am lost how to fix it. I made a new fiddle with the new html so you can see the problem http://jsfiddle.net/a9Xj6/5/

Answer (score 0):

Adding a pointer style to regions can be achieved with an easy css fix:

```
path.jvectormap-region {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```